# Is there any good way to show camera again when user taps User Photo option after taking photo?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any good way to show camera again when user taps User Photo option after taking photo? In my current app, this is how I am showing camera again but it delays for some time before reopening camera.

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        let dt = DateTime()
        let newImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: (image.cgImage)!,scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)
        let newImage1 = self.textToImages(drawText: dt as NSString, inImage: newImage, atPoint:CGPoint(x: (newImage.size.width/4),y: (newImage.size.height-50)))
        let Imagename = self.Create_imageName(index:self.index)
        let imageinfo = imageDescription(imageName: "\(Imagename).jpg", image: newImage1)
        self.imageArray.append(imageinfo)
        self.saveImages(img:newImage1,index:self.index,name:Imagename)
        self.index += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageCollectionView?.reloadData()
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        self.camera()
    }
}
```

Comment: call this `self.camera()` in after `self.imageCollectionView?.reloadData()`

Comment: is this working or not

Comment: happy to hear....